# java spring 3.0 mvc

Tags: java, spring

whats the root cause of getting folloeing exception:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.`]]

with root cause

its in server log.
Whenever i try to make a post request to this url with an xml data...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with bogus characters in your XML file but I think I've seen this before when there were 2 versions of Spring on the classpath.

Can you post your XML file and also list the contents of your classpath.